# Request for reopening - edition comparison

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

This question was closed as off-topic:

[Does the AC 3 pre-order collector editions lack content available with the special edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76616/does-the-ac-3-pre-order-collector-editions-lack-content-available-with-the-speci)

Two reasons for that were mentioned in the comments, and I absolutely disagree with both.

#### 1) The "shopping advice" argument

The question is asking for comparing content between different editions of the same game. This is 100% objective - a dry list such as "this module is included, but that module isn't". There's no element of advice or recommendation in this question. The question is even explicit about what the OP is looking for - an edition containing all the different modules.

Further, we have many edition-comparison questions:

- [What is the difference between borderlands and borderlands GOTY edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20048/what-is-the-difference-between-borderlands-and-borderlands-goty-edition)
- [What features does Rock Band 3 for Wii lack?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30882/what-features-does-rock-band-3-for-wii-lack)
- [Which versions of Final Fantasy VI include multiplayer battle support?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25265/which-versions-of-final-fantasy-vi-include-multiplayer-battle-support)
- [Is there a functional difference between the console and PC versions of the LEGO games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30193/is-there-a-functional-difference-between-the-console-and-pc-versions-of-the-lego)
- [Civilization V versions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11498/civilization-v-versions)
- ... and more

And I consider all to be good questions - fitting to Q&A, objective, helpful for many people, relevant for gamers, etc.

#### 2) Unreleased game

The various editions of the games are available for pre-ordering, as in *now*. This isn't asking about gameplay questions or technical support questions or anything like that, it's instead asking about what we could say is a "released" aspect of the game - the various editions.

So while this could be argued to be about an unreleased game and thus everything can still change, I personally think this sort of information is extremely useful **right now** and will probably **continue** to be useful after the game is released, so I don't think closing it is the right thing to do. Also, considering there are already box art versions and pre-ordering payments, this will probably not change.

Comment: I've voted to reopen based on your post here. It was a little unclear to me from the initial post how much information there was that was non-speculative, my mistake. :)

Comment: Would you consider [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54232/what-are-the-various-promotional-versions-of-mass-effect-3-i-e-gamestop-best) to fall into the same category? It frustrates me when users stand firm against some questions/users and not others.

Comment: @Adanion yes, it seems to fall under the same category. Also, I'm sorry you find it frustrating that I don't take similar action on similar posts, but I don't actually read *all* the posts on the site - I doubt many do that. If there's a specific post you want to draw attention to, a good way is to post it on meta or discuss it on chat, so it will be more visible. I *do* monitor all *meta* questions, and so do many others.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's valid. I've actually spent time trying to work this out myself.

As there are a number of different editions each with different add-ons and access to different things it makes sense that someone could answer with a list of all the possible extras and which versions they are included in.

Personally I plumped for a pre-order of the cheapest edition mainly because I couldn't work out which edition included what.

I do agree with some people that it could have been phrased a little clearer, but we aren't all perfect, and I do feel that sometimes people are too quick to dismiss questions rather than explain themselves in a more verbose manner. It makes me sad that we have to close so many questions with a just a 'Not on topic' or 'Read the FAQ' as it creates a negative experience for the users and especially newcomers. Granted, it's not a forum, but a little more friendliness never hurt anyone :)

Edit, Actually a quick look turned up this table, which would have made an ideal answer.
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassin's_Creed_III#Retail_editions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassin%27s_Creed_III#Retail_editions) Although my pre-order from Amazon comes with 'with Captain of the Aquila pre-order bonus' so again, there is more to it than just the editions! ;)

Answer (score -4):

Shopping Advice doesn't just include "What should I buy?", it also extends to "Where can I buy it?". Which is what this question appears to be asking, and therefore it is off-topic.

See also: [Do we allow questions about where to buy things?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2707/do-we-allow-questions-about-where-to-buy-things)

Comment: Except this isn't really, *where can I buy it*, but rather *Does Edition X include Feature A from Edition Y?*. The fact that the difference between the versions is point of purchase is immaterial to the topicality of the question.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz His closing question is what makes me believe it is "Where": *Is there no way to get the "full" game with all the available content?* However, after reading the question/comments a few times that doesn't seem to be the OPs intent, so I'll cast a vote to re-open.