# Why is asking for payment-options flagged off-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

We got a question a few minutes ago [which can be found here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/206876/i-want-to-buy-xbox-live-gold-12-month-with-bitcoin/). I want to know why this got flagged as off-topic because i can't see reason for that.

aytimothy gives the reason that this is about "pay money online" so i want to know if it would be off-topic if i ask i.e. if Riot (League of Legends) supports Bitcoins to buy skins.

What about all those free to play games out there, i'm not allowed to ask several questions about the pay model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excerpt from question:

> Ive been tried many times to find where i can buy xbox subscription for 12 month with bitcoin or paypal.

He's not asking if Blizzard accepts bitcoins as payment, but for a list of places that do accept Bitcoins as payments, and also sells WoW subscriptions. That's a "Where to buy" question, [which is a question type we don't allow on the site](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2709/8350).

> aytimothy gives the reason that this is about "pay money online" so i want to know if it would be off-topic if i ask i.e. if Riot (League of Legends) supports Bitcoins to buy skins.

This isn't really relevant to the the reason the question is off-topic, since your hypothetical question wouldn't be "where to buy", which is why the question is off-topic.

> What about all those free to play games out there, i'm not allowed to ask several questions about the pay model?

There's no way I can make a general sweeping statement about this. Some questions like this will be allowed, and some won't.

With regards to this comment:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about ways to pay money online.

I wouldn't worry too much about it, since it really has nothing to do with why the question is off-topic (tbh I'm not even completely sure what he means). It's possible the user voted voted for off-topic with the wrong reasoning, but the question *is* off-topic, and without him clarifying what he meant then it's not really possible to address the correctness of his reasoning.

EDIT: Just realized that aytimothy  seems to view the question more about how to use bitcoin, as opposed to asking which sites accept Bitcoin as payment which also sell WoW subscriptions. A question asking how to use Bitcoin is off-topic for the site, since it's not a Gaming question, it's a Bitcoin question. How to convert Bitcoin to cash, or how to use Bitcoin on sites which don't accept it, is very squarely outside our realm.

Comment: So it's not about the payment thing itself but about the way the question is asked? Just to get you 100% right. Lets say he would've asked "is it possible to buy a xbox sub with bitcoins" then it wouldn't be off-topic?

Comment: @Nitro.de The payment part isn't why I'd consider the question to be off-topic, no, given that I'm reading the question as "Where can I buy WoW subscriptions with Bitcoin?". If you remove the "with bitcoin" part you'd be left with "Where can I buy WoW subscriptions?", which is off-topic, and adding the condition of bitcoin doesn't really change that,.

Comment: Okay i got it thank you guys even if i dont know how you came up with blizzard and wow if the question is about microsoft and xbox^^

Comment: @Nitro.de: I would still say "is it possible" is off-topic, because despite the wording, it's still asking the same thing as "Where can I buy". Also, I just realized I swapped over to WoW instead of XBOX part way through... the same logic applies, but just wanted to say I meant XBOX, in case there is any confusion.

Comment: @Nitro.de Yeah, haha, I have no idea how I switched to WoW half-way through my post. The same logic applies, though.

Comment: @Wipqozn - Xbox live could be considered a tool that gamers use, correct? Following that logic further, asking about a specific configuration/setting on said gaming tool would be on-topic, such as asking about parental control settings, changing display name, syncing achievements etc - what makes the "payment settings" any different? It isn't a "Where to buy" question/shopping rec - which are considered off topic and closed for being subjective, its a "How can I do X with my Y" question. Even if the answer is "not directly possible", the question bears none of the hallmarks of a shopping rec.

Comment: @Robotnik: I didn't realize Microsoft accepted bitcoins, which does change things, so I've voted to re-open the question. However, although I agree this question is on-topic, I've [started a meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10291/8350) discussing if questions asking which currency a specific gaming applications accepts is on-topic.

Comment: Personally, I feel that we've twisted that question well beyond what the asker wanted to know, and that it really should be rolled back and closed again.  He didn't want to know if he could use bitcoins on Microsoft's site; he wanted to know how he could buy a specific product with bitcoins.

Comment: @Frank - I just made this point on the post as well. By changing it to 'products on Xbox Live' instead of 'Xbox Live Subscription' I think it's a step too far. If we roll it back to the version which still talks about subscriptions I'd be more comfortable with it.

Comment: @Frank: I've edited the question to only be able subs. However, I disagree the question should be closed. The key part of the question is that asker wanted to know how to buy a a sub with bitcoins, refocusing that to asking how to do so on XBOX live directly doesn't change that key concept. It also changes it from "Where to buy" to "How do I use this feature of Xbox Live?"

Comment: @Frank: you'll probably want to chime in on [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10291/8350)

Comment: I agree the question as currently worded is on-topic.  However, the edits have also twisted it well beyond what the asker was actually asking.  All he wanted was to know where to buy a specific product with a specific currency.  The fact that you can buy it from the original source is irrelevant to the base question, but it's been focused on that due to the answer it received.  That's twisting the question beyond asker intent, exactly what we shouldn't be doing.

Comment: Based on [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/10276/20456), we should really be rolling back that edit, and re-closing the question.  Let someone who's actually interested in using Bitcoin to buy a subscription from Microsoft ask the question, rather than us stretching the question.

Comment: @Frank - I think that comes down to interpretation. I've looked at the original post, reviewed the edits, read the comments by the OP - as it stands it's definitely the question he wanted to ask, even if his English wasn't so good. Sure the title of the original uses the term 'where to buy', but in the context of what's in the body I take that more as "Where is the 'pay by Bitcoin' option on XBL" and not "looking for places to buy XBL subscriptions"